# How to keep the cmd open until a command executed fully?

Tags: windows, batch-file, cmd

I am creating a batch file,which invoke cmd and execute maven build command and cmd has to wait until the command executed fully.

Here is my code,

```
Myfile.bat

cd E:\MobileGateWay & E:

mvn clean install package 

cmd \K
```

But on executing the above batch file. It invokes cmd and execute maven build command and cmd hide immediately.
I want to keep the cmd open until the maven build command executed fully.

Can anyone help me on this?

Comment: `cmd \K` should be `cmd /K` - `\\` is a path-separator, `/` is a switch

Comment: is the `Myfile.bat` called and is it another batch file? try with `call Myfile.bat` if it is.

Comment: As per [Maven on Windows](http://maven.apache.org/guides/getting-started/windows-prerequisites.html), `mvn` should refer to `mvn.cmd`, right? Use  `CALL mvn clean install package`.

Comment: @JosefZ,@npocmaka.It's Working.thanks...